LWR Community LWC engine ERROR
I have 2 LWR communities on my sandbox. For some reason only one of them is impacted with following issue.
Error: [LWC error]: LWC WARNING: current engine is v6.4.1, but template was compiled with v5.0.9
Please update your compiled code or LWC engine so that the version match.
In the impacted community site, I have created a new empty page and put an empty LWC with just static text. This works fine. The problems starts when I add a lightning-icon. Then the error shows up in the console and the icon is missing.
Additional information:
In the community preview there is no error and the icon shows. The problem is only on the published site.
We are not using jest tests. There is nothing in the package.json/package-lock.json with either of the versions mentioned in the error message.
Please save me.
EDIT:
It looks like it was caused by SF preview update in our sandbox. The impacted LWR community was created before the update and the unimpacted one was created after the update. Also the cause of the error was a lightning-icon called action:approval. Once we changed the icon for another one the error went away.
